# Runing a NodeJS app outside its directory

Tags: node.js, linux

I've written a NodeJS-app  like the following:

```
  myapp
    ├── app.js
    ├─┬ public
    │ └─┬ scripts
    │   ├── css
    │   └── js
    ├
    └─┬ views
      ├── index.ejs
```

The app is saved under the folder **myapp*. to run it I use this bash-script [for other reasons]:

**app.sh**

```
#!bin/bash 
node  app.js
```

the shell is also saved in the same folder **myapp**.  In order to run the app properly, I need to be in the folder like :

```
user@pi:cd myapp/
user@pi: ./app.sh
```

but if  I'm outside the directory for instance :

```
user@pi:./myapp/app.sh
```

The app runs but without its layout !!! 
any idea why I'm having the behavior?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run bash outside of the desired folder, your file location will be different from your current working directory. What you should do to solve the problem is to add a `cd` to your bash file, to change the working directory to the file location:

```sh
#!bin/bash 
cd myapp/
node app.js
```